# Upgrade to 18.04 LTS from 16.04 on i386

Tags: upgrade, 18.04, 32-bit

I saw that 18.04 LTS only supports amd64. However I can upgrade to it from my 16.04 via the software updater. I have i386 though. Should I do it or stick with 16.04 LTS to avoid any problems with the system?

Comment: Lubuntu offers a 32 bit version of 18.04 ... install it separately as a dual boot ... as always try it before installing using the LiveUSB option

Comment: @ScottStensland - Just FYI - Lubuntu is no longer wanting to support older hardware either - https://lubuntu.me/taking-a-new-direction/

Answer (score 1):

I can't remember where this was talked about but I would stay in 16.04 in your case. Jumping to 18.04 even if it has your packages (probably the same 16.04 ones) could create issues. I think they tried removing the 17.10 to 18.04 upgrade from an i386 but forgot this one. In any case, if you are able to upgrade but everyone knows 18.04 is only oriented towards 64bit, it would be a bad idea to do the upgrade.

Comment: I believe they pulled the images (iso) for 32 bit (for the most part) with 17.10 and the server image (iso) for 18.04 - https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-release/2017-December/004257.html but I believe you can still obtain the mini .iso - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD . The 32 bit repositories remain but be aware 32 bit hardware for the most part is at least 10 years old and support for old 32 bit hardware is diminishing

Comment: Yes correct, the repositories remain but I feel it would be a bad idea to upgrade. Not to mention the fact that, with new kernel releases, old drivers get removed (Look at 4.18 for example and each previous one). So it would create a nightmare for the OP.